# Is there a way to show custom text based on column value in Power BI Desktop?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

lets say I have a table like this:

| Name | Value | Month | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 20.2 | 1 | 2022 |
| John | 221.2 | 7 | 2022 |
| John | 320.2 | 1 | 2023 |
| Miles | 301.1 | 1 | 2022 |
| Miles | 301.2 | 7 | 2022 |
| Miles | 33.5 | 1 | 2023 |

I'm showing the data in a matrix visual and filtering according to year and month with a data slicer. For example I can filter for "2022" and "1", to show me all these data.

Is it possible to create a visual or give the matrix a title with a text format like for example "Month: 1, Year:2022", where the value are taken from the month and year column and according to the filter from the slicer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a measure using SELECTEDVALUE(), e.g.

```
Title = "Year:" & SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Year]) & ", Month:" & SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Month])"
```

Refer to the columns you are using in your slicers.